# using decision tree to describe high dimensional data

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I have a dataset with 6 numeric columns and one dichotomous factor contain yes and no. I would like to understand when yes is more likely given the 6 numeric columns.

I intend to use a decision tree (e.g. rpart in R) and wonder if I have to watch out for over-fitting in this descriptive rather than predictive scenario?

I would simply search for good hyper-parameters using AUC as performance metric but restrict the size of the tree to keep it consumable.

What do you think?

Comment: How many is your data? You could consider the pre-prunning or post-prunning process. Refer to http://www.saedsayad.com/decision_tree_overfitting.htm for a more detail of the process. As for your question, you could also refer to the link https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/323/how-can-we-calculate-auc-for-a-simple-decision-tree as it explain to you the ROC but I do think that with your current way could be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to watch out for overfitting, if your goal is interpretation. Specifically, if you are going to use R and rpart, once you build your model, the output will show you a table with `cp` values, these are used to prune the tree and reduce it's size (and overfitting). Normally you would choose the `cp` value which returns the minimal error. Once you've chosen the desired value you rerun your model with the additional `cp` argument to prune the tree.

Comment: Can you use decision tree for one dimensional data ?

Comment: @MUK Yes, you can have multiple splits (nodes) on the same variable in the same tree.